# BackgroundUploader.getCurrentUploadsAsync() is returning most of the transfers I've ever done

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, background-transfer

I'm working on a Metro app that will upload and download some files.  MS provides a couple examples:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Upload-457ae763
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61

The first one is an uploader app, and the 2nd is a downloader app.  As Win8 can suspend and kill an app when it goes out of focus, the downloader app provides for retrieving the active downloads so I can start receiving updates about the status.  The Uploader app does not.  I have tried to add this functionality, but getCurrentUploadsAsync() is returning 18 transfers that I have already completed.  I have tried everything I can think of to remove these transfers, but it does not change the results of getCurrentUploadsAsync().

Does anyone know how to clear out "dead" BackgroundTransfers in WinRT?

Comment: I figured it out.  `getCurrentUploadsAsync` returns a list of something or other... a container? which contains an `operation` object.  I thought the important part was the `operation`, but you can call `cancel` on the container.  
A more interesting problem now is "can you restart a _dead_ transfer?"
If it's not dead, you can start monitoring it again, but i haven't been able to get it to do anything interesting...

Comment: Put your finding in the answer and mark it as the answer so this doesn't appear to be an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the cancel method like explained there : http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2013/02/05/winrt-how-to-cancel-a-background-download-operation/

```
theDownloadOperation.AttachAsync().Cancel();
```